# Wordpress url not including category on main page

Tags: wordpress, url

I am new to wordpress so trying to figure out something which I cannot and asking you guys. Please help if you know.

I have issues with URL formation in Wordpress. I want to show articles' category name in URL, so  I am using `Permlinks -> custom structure` which is like `/%category%/%postname%.htm` I then pasted code given by WP in `.htaccess` file. So now articles use `http://mysite/category1/article1.htm` URL.

But then on index.php any links inside article shows URL as`http://mysite/article2.htm` and hence 404. I am using `><a href="article2.htm">Article2</a>` inside a post. If I open `http://mysite/category1/article1.htm` then above link will show as `http://mysite/category2/article2.htm` which is the correct URL.

Can someone plese help me figure out correct way? Using above configuration, it works fine for all links when open individual posts but only main index.php does not include category name. Just to note, URLs in Recent Posts also show correct URL.

Comment: @Set Sail Media is correct. If you have embedded links in the content of a post, changing your **permalink** structure will have no effect on them. If there aren't many, just update them manually.

Answer (score 2):

If the links are hardcoded inside the article itself, there's nothing inside WordPress PHP or settings to change. You just need to edit the post content and update the HTML link URLs using the new permalink structure, within Posts and/or Pages tab.

You can also try a plugin like `Redirection` which will redirect old post permalinks to the new (correct) permalink format.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Do you have a live example URL somewhere? Have you manually created an excerpt, which might be used on the index and contain an old link, vs. the full edited post content used on the single?

Comment: There is no excerpt as of now to be used on homepage and it uses latest posts thats why the above issue.

Comment: Actually I am importing thousands of articles from old website and importing to WP. So to correct this issue, if I were to change links URL, what should I use for category? And also it will fix issue on homepage but will create issue on individual page?